# Why is the button icon not displayed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, button, svg-icon

Here is the code of my html file in LWC:

```
<div>
    <lightning-button label="Update" onclick={connectedCallback} class="slds-button_icon">
        <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sync/svg/symbols.svg#sync"></use>
        </svg>
    </lightning-button>
</div>
```

Why a button with a label, and not an icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use icon-name to specify an icon:

```
<lightning-button icon-name="utility:sync" ...>
</lightning-button>
```

See [this demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/6jtr2FcbhS4GTMljuzGv/src/app.js).